# useContext give error Cannot read property '...' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I need help with this issue, my app component as in the image below. I want to store track object `inselectedTrack` in the state using `useState` when I click on the view details button. Then use it to display track details in  instead of making another fetch from API to get tack details, but when I use `useContext` inside  give me this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedTrack' of undefined`.
[React Components](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUywt.png)

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import Search from '../tracks/Search';
import Tracks from '../tracks/Tracks';
import Footer from './Footer';
import TrackContextProvider from '../../contexts/TrackContext';

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <TrackContextProvider>
        <Header />
        <Search />
        <Tracks />
        <Footer />
      </TrackContextProvider>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Main;
```

TrackContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';
export const TrackContext = createContext();

const TrackContextProvider = props => {

  const [tracks, setTracks] = useState([]);
  const [selectedTrack, setSelectedTrack] = useState([{}]);

  const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_MUSICXMATCH_KEY;

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/chart.tracks.get?chart_name=top&page=1&page_size=10&country=fr&f_has_lyrics=1&apikey=${API_KEY}`
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setTracks(data.message.body.track_list))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    // to disable the warning rule of missing dependency
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  // state for heading
  const [heading, setHeading] = useState(['Top 10 Tracks']);

  return (
    <TrackContext.Provider value={{ tracks, heading, selectedTrack, setSelectedTrack }}>
      {props.children}
    </TrackContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default TrackContextProvider;
```

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { TrackContext } from '../../contexts/TrackContext';

const TrackDetails = () => {
  const { selectedTrack } = useContext(TrackContext);
  console.log(selectedTrack);
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <Link to="/">
        <button>Go Back</button>
      </Link>
      <div>
        {selectedTrack === undefined ? (
          <p>loading ...</p>
        ) : (
          <h3>
            {selectedTrack.track.track_name} by {selectedTrack.track.artist_name}
          </h3>
        )}
        <p>lyrics.............</p>
        <div>Album Id: </div>)
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default TrackDetails;
```

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { TrackContext } from '../../contexts/TrackContext';

const Track = ({ trackInfo }) => {
  const { selectedTrack, setSelectedTrack } = useContext(TrackContext);

  const handleClick = e => {
    setSelectedTrack(trackInfo);
  };

  console.log(selectedTrack);

  return (
    <li>
      <div>{trackInfo.track.artist_name}</div>
      <div>Track: {trackInfo.track.track_name}</div>
      <div>Album:{trackInfo.track.album_name}</div>
      <div>Rating:{trackInfo.track.track_rating}</div>
      <Link to={{ pathname: `/trackdetails/${trackInfo.track.track_id}`, param1: selectedTrack }}>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>> View Lyric</button>
      </Link>
    </li>
  );
};

export default Track;
```

UPDATE: adding Tracks component

```
import React, { useContext, Fragment } from 'react';
import Track from './Track';
import { TrackContext } from '../../contexts/TrackContext';

const Tracks = () => {
  const { heading, tracks } = useContext(TrackContext);

  const tracksList = tracks.map(trackInfo => {
    return <Track trackInfo={trackInfo} key={trackInfo.track.track_id} />;
  });
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <p>{heading}</p>
      {tracks.length ? <ul>{tracksList}</ul> : <p>loading...</p>}
    </Fragment>
  );
};

export default Tracks;
```

Comment: can you also provide the code for `Tracks`?

Comment: Try moving `TrackContext` creation into the main file, and import into `TrackContext` as well

Comment: I have added the `Tracks component`. @PaulFitzgerald

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue here is that since the `selectedTrack` is loaded asynchronously, when it is accessed from the context, it is undefined (you can get around the `TrackContext` being `undefined` by passing in a default value in the `createContext` call). Since the selectedTrack variable is populated anychronously, you should store it in a `Ref` with `useRef` hook, and return that ref as part of the context value. That way you would get the latest value of `selectedTrack` from any consumer of that context.

```js
const selectedTracks = useRef([]);
useEffect(() => {
    fetch(
      `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.musixmatch.com/ws/1.1/chart.tracks.get?chart_name=top&page=1&page_size=10&country=fr&f_has_lyrics=1&apikey=${API_KEY}`
    )
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        selectedTrack.current = data.message.body.track_list;
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    // to disable the warning rule of missing dependency
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);
```

Comment: could you clarify how to return that ref as part of the context value?

Comment: I would return it the same way you return `selectedTrack` currently, i.e., in the `value` of the Track Context Provider. When you access it from the context, since it is a `ref`, you have to access it like `const { selectedTracks } = useContext(TrackContext); console.log(selectedTracks.current);` to get the value that is returned from API. https://codesandbox.io/s/usefocus-2l1lh?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Thanks for your help, but how can I access `selectedTracks` in <TrackDetails /> when I tried to do const { selectedTracks } = useContext(TrackContext);

Comment: It gives me error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedTracks'`. Is it possible to use `useContext` inside react-router link (`TrackDetails component`) or not?

Comment: The reason for the `undefined` error is probably because the TrackContext has not been initialized. You can set a default value in the `createContext()` call, In the code-sandbox example I posted above, I'm creating the context with a default empty object like `const TrackContext = createContext({});`. I've also updated the code-sandbox to display the selected tracks. Hope it helps!!

Comment: Sure thing. If my solution did fix your problem, it would be helpful, for others facing the same issue, to mark that as the correct answer.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mark it. I have just marked it now. thanks for your help.

Comment: @Scorpion-Prince adding {} empty object to createContext worked in my case. Thanks a ton.